# NSAttributedString to HTML, NSObliquenessAttributeName cannot convert

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

`NSAttributedString` to HTML, `NSObliquenessAttributeName` cannot convert.
Can you tell me what's the solution

```
- (NSString *)attriToStrWithAttri:(NSAttributedString *)attri{
    NSDictionary *tempDic = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                              NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUnicodeStringEncoding)};
    NSData *htmlData = [attri dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attri.length)
                         documentAttributes:tempDic
                                      error:nil];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData
                                 encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
}
```

This problem bothering me for a long time, someone can provide a solution?

Comment: Can you post some code for us to have a look at? :-)

Comment: Please edit your question with the above amendments so it's easy for people to find.